# Get tags array from HTML

Tags: java, android, html, json, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to get the tags from HTML to process the text it to draw text in Canvas, now I'm getting the tree like this:

```
    private JSONArray printTree (NodeList nodes, int level, JSONArray data) throws JSONException {

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength (); i++) {

            Node node = nodes.item (i);

            JSONObject data2 = new JSONObject ();

            if (node.getNodeType () != Node.TEXT_NODE) {

                data2.put ("tag", node.getNodeName ());
                data2.put ("body", printTree (node.getChildNodes (), level, new JSONArray ()));

            } else data2.put ("text", node.getNodeValue ());

            data.put (data2);

        }

        return data;

    }
```

so this html

```
<p>
  <b>
    <i>
      text1
    </i>
    text2
  </b>
</p>
```

returns the following array:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "p",
    "body": [
      {
        "tag": "b",
        "body": [
          {
            "tag": "i",
            "body": [
              {
                "text": "text1",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "text": "text2",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But how can I get the tags associated with text, according its nested level, e. g., because I need to process every text in tags with this tags?

```
[
  {
    "text": "text1",
    "tags": ["p","b","i"]
  },
  {
    "text": "text2",
    "tags": ["p","b"]
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you are better off using an HTML parser like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Comment: @Smile thanks, but there's problem how to build an array as I need, not to parse the HTML, because I've done it.